# JasperReport gets NullPointerException when detail band takes Split Type as Prevent

Tags: nullpointerexception, jasper-reports

*Environment:*

- Jboss 5.2
- Javaee 6
- JasperReport 6.5.1

I'm getting a NullPointerError in JasperReport classes when I use in a detail band the Split Type = Prevent but when I use Split Type = NULL works well.

**Report**

```
...
<band height="101" splitType="Prevent">
            <subreport>
                <reportElement x="0" y="27" width="555" height="70" uuid="f3948499-a572-4d2c-82ab-b24760874e7d"/>
                <subreportParameter name="refCurs">
                    <subreportParameterExpression><![CDATA[$F{referenciacurs}]]></subreportParameterExpression>
                </subreportParameter>
                <connectionExpression><![CDATA[$P{REPORT_CONNECTION}]]></connectionExpression>
                <subreportExpression><![CDATA[$P{217_subParticipants}]]></subreportExpression>
            </subreport>
...
```

**Error trace**

```
2018-09-20 14:41:37,049 ERROR [org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.[jboss.web].[localhost].[/accforback].[Faces Servlet]] (http-10.215.15.23-8080-6) Servlet.service() para servlet Faces Servlet lanzó excepción
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fill.JRFillTextElement.setPrintText(JRFillTextElement.java:1057)
    at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fill.JRFillStaticText.fill(JRFillStaticText.java:215)
    at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fill.JRFillElementContainer.fillElements(JRFillElementContainer.java:1039)
    at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fill.JRFillBand.fill(JRFillBand.java:454)
    at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fill.JRFillBand.fill(JRFillBand.java:413)
    at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fill.JRFillBand.refill(JRFillBand.java:385)
    at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fill.JRVerticalFiller.fillColumnBand(JRVerticalFiller.java:2608)
    at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fill.JRVerticalFiller.fillDetail(JRVerticalFiller.java:791)
    at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fill.JRVerticalFiller.fillReportStart(JRVerticalFiller.java:252)
    at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fill.JRVerticalFiller.fillReport(JRVerticalFiller.java:99)
    at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fill.JRBaseFiller.fill(JRBaseFiller.java:609)
    at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fill.BaseReportFiller.fill(BaseReportFiller.java:387)
    at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fill.JRFiller.fill(JRFiller.java:109)
    at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.JasperFillManager.fill(JasperFillManager.java:456)
    at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.JasperFillManager.fillReport(JasperFillManager.java:863)
    at es.app.play.back.util.ReportManager.enviaDatos(ReportManager.java:140)
    at es.app.play.back.util.ReportManager.run(ReportManager.java:64)
    at es.app.play.back.controller.informes.ExecutarInformeController.compileReport(ExecutarInformeController.java:243)
    at es.app.play.back.controller.informes.ExecutarInformeController.report(ExecutarInformeController.java:114)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    at org.apache.el.parser.AstValue.invoke(AstValue.java:170)
    at org.apache.el.MethodExpressionImpl.invoke(MethodExpressionImpl.java:276)
    at com.sun.faces.facelets.el.TagMethodExpression.invoke(TagMethodExpression.java:105)
    at javax.faces.component.MethodBindingMethodExpressionAdapter.invoke(MethodBindingMethodExpressionAdapter.java:88)
    at com.sun.faces.application.ActionListenerImpl.processAction(ActionListenerImpl.java:102)
    at javax.faces.component.UICommand.broadcast(UICommand.java:315)
    at javax.faces.component.UIViewRoot.broadcastEvents(UIViewRoot.java:794)
    at javax.faces.component.UIViewRoot.processApplication(UIViewRoot.java:1259)
    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.InvokeApplicationPhase.execute(InvokeApplicationPhase.java:81)
    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.Phase.doPhase(Phase.java:101)
    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.LifecycleImpl.execute(LifecycleImpl.java:118)
    at javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet.service(FacesServlet.java:593)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:290)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
    at org.primefaces.webapp.filter.FileUploadFilter.doFilter(FileUploadFilter.java:103)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:235)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
    at es.app.play.back.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilter(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:21)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:235)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
    at org.jboss.web.tomcat.filters.ReplyHeaderFilter.doFilter(ReplyHeaderFilter.java:96)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:235)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:235)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:191)
    at org.jboss.web.tomcat.security.SecurityAssociationValve.invoke(SecurityAssociationValve.java:183)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:534)
    at org.jboss.web.tomcat.security.JaccContextValve.invoke(JaccContextValve.java:95)
    at org.jboss.web.tomcat.security.SecurityContextEstablishmentValve.process(SecurityContextEstablishmentValve.java:126)
    at org.jboss.web.tomcat.security.SecurityContextEstablishmentValve.invoke(SecurityContextEstablishmentValve.java:70)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:127)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:102)
    at org.jboss.web.tomcat.service.jca.CachedConnectionValve.invoke(CachedConnectionValve.java:158)
    at es.caib.loginModule.auth.FormResourcesValve.invoke(FormResourcesValve.java:31)
    at es.caib.loginModule.auth.ClientIPValve.invoke(ClientIPValve.java:62)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:109)
    at org.jboss.web.tomcat.service.request.ActiveRequestResponseCacheValve.internalProcess(ActiveRequestResponseCacheValve.java:74)
    at org.jboss.web.tomcat.service.request.ActiveRequestResponseCacheValve.invoke(ActiveRequestResponseCacheValve.java:47)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:330)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.process(Http11Processor.java:829)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol$Http11ConnectionHandler.process(Http11Protocol.java:599)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$Worker.run(JIoEndpoint.java:451)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

Comment: Joe consider to accept the answer if it pointed you to a solution

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is a bug in JasperReport version 6.5.1 - see https://community.jaspersoft.com/jasperreports-library/issues/10486 and https://community.jaspersoft.com/jasperreports-library/issues/10761

You can upgrade JasperReports on version 6.6.x or you can workaround it by setting the following property in your *jasperreports.properties* to avoid the error:

```
net.sf.jasperreports.legacy.band.evaluation.enabled=true
```